# Skipping ahead on stronglift

Tags: stronglifts

I'm relatively new to mendhi's program of 5x5 and i was wondering if you have to start all the way from what is listed on the program. I can do 2 plates, 5 sets of 5 with ease but on the program it tells me to start with 110, is it necessary to start all the way there? Can't i just start at 225 or atleast a few weights down? What are your suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you should always lift at a weight where you can only barely complete the exercises. I have even heard that not increasing weight as you progress will not only make you stagnate, but potentially even reduce strength.

Answer (score 1):

You can, and you may, there's not much need to start that low unless you are new to that particular lift, just start at a weight which you will achieve in the fourth week. Which means, if you are currently lifting 225, you should start from 160-165 (5 pound increase each workout), that'll be more than enough.